# ionic:Runtime Error Cannot find module "../pages/home/home"

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to make an app in ionic, so I add some custom page in ionic by command :

`ionic g page user`

But I start ionic server it show error

> Runtime Error Cannot find module "../pages/home/home"

[click for error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vdfx.png)

Comment: Try executing `npm run build`

Comment: Can you please add your file organisation (using a screenshot can be great) and the folder where you called "ionic g page user"? Also, we will need your app.module file, as the problem seems to come from here.

Comment: thanks Supamiu, I found the solution by changing in app.module.ts and app.components.ts file

Answer (score 2):

If the app tells you that it misses a file, that's because there's somewhere where you imported this file and it doesn't exist (anymore? maybe you deleted it and forgot to delete an import)

You should make a project-wide text search using grep or your favorite ide to find where you are importing "../pages/home/home".

Your error doesn't come from your `ionic g page user` command as this command only generates a page named user.

It seems like you created a page called home and deleted it without deleting imports.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I was github clone code.
But this is not the problem with the code itself, but because I used cnpm (npm of the Chinese version).
Uninstall npm, install npm. The problem is solved